# Cordova slow HTTP TTFB

Tags: android, angular, cordova, http

We are using Angular 9 and Cordova to build our Hyprid app on Android. The problem is that some (1 out of 5) http requests are taking very long. It does not happen when I open the app in the mobile Chrome browser. I checked the chrome dev tools and its always the "Waiting (TTFB)" which takes 2-3 seconds. Normaly it takes 50ms. I dont think that this is a server issue, because it works just fine on the mobile browser.

[image]

Comment: Cordova is not suppose to run fast on browser, it's for mobile.
So I guess that's normal

Comment: The screenshot is from the Chrome Devtools connected to the webview from an android device

Comment: I think I have found the problem. In the catlog from Android the phone is sometimes scanning for Wifi (Searching for Wifi Hotspots?) and while it is scanning the webrequests are waiting. I dont know why, but it happens only with cordova applications. This scanning times were massively reduced by turning of 5ghz wifi. I think it depends on the devices, too.